# How to ignore the subject-case in commitlint?

Tags: commitlint

I am trying to ignore the case in commitlint, but unfortunately there is not enough documentation how to ignore a specific rule.

I tried to add and allow all cases always in the subject-case rule, but this won't allow mixed sentences like (sentence-case and camel-case in one subject)

> git commit -m "feat(auth): New userModel"

My configuration file:

```js
import type { UserConfig } from '@commitlint/types';

const Configuration: UserConfig = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
  rules: {
    'subject-case': [
      2,
      'always',
      [
        'lower-case',
        'upper-case',
        'camel-case',
        'kebab-case',
        'pascal-case',
        'sentence-case',
        'snake-case',
        'start-case',
      ]
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = Configuration;
```

Comment: why don't you just disable the rule?

Comment: how to disable it ? @knocte

Comment: @lisonge use 0 (disabled) instead of 2 (error); NB: 1 would mean 'warning'

Comment: The key to the problem is that the parameter is explicitly specified for the Commitlint, which will not read the configuration file by default. pnpm exec commitlint --config commitlint.config.cts --edit ${1}

Answer (score 1):

Keep the config as below,

```js
const Configuration: UserConfig = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
  rules: {
    'subject-case': [
      2,
      'never',
      [
        'upper-case',
        'pascal-case',
        'start-case',
      ]
    ]
  }
};
```